# Не пойму в чем ошибка в коде си

Tags: c, стек

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef int Item;
Item *STACK_AR;
int STACK_SIZE, key1;

void stack_creation( Item *STACK_AR, int STACK_SIZE );

int push_stack( Item *STACK_AR,
                int *t ); //вставка элемента в вершину стека

int main()
{
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "rus" );

    for( ;; ) {
        printf( "Введите количество элементов\n" );
        scanf( "%d", &STACK_SIZE );
        int top = -1;
        int *t;
        t = &top;
        stack_creation( STACK_AR, STACK_SIZE );
        printf( "Втавить элемент в вершину стека — 1\n" );
        scanf( "%d", &key1 );

        switch( key1 ) {
            case 1:
                top = push_stack( STACK_AR, t );
                break;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void stack_creation( Item *STACK_AR, int STACK_SIZE )
{
    STACK_AR = ( Item * )malloc( STACK_SIZE * sizeof(
                                     Item ) ); //динамическое выделение памяти под массив
}

int push_stack( Item *STACK_AR,
                int *t ) //вставка элемента в вершину стека
{
    Item n;
    ( *t )++;

    if( ( *t ) < STACK_SIZE ) {
        printf( "Введите элемент\n" );
        scanf( "%d", &n );
        STACK_AR[( *t )] = n; //ошибка возникает в этом месте!!
    }
    else {
        ( *t )--;
        printf( "Стек полный!!!\n" );
    }
    return ( *t );
}
```

Comment: а какая ошибка? [mcve] может?

Answer (score 1):

По крайней мере в этом предложении

```
printf("Введите количество элементов\n");
    scanf("%d",&SIZE);
```

вы используете имя `SIZE`, которое у вас не определено.

А самое главное, что у вас стек никогда не создается, так как в этой функции

```
void stack_creation(Item*STACK_AR,int STACK_SIZE)
{
    STACK_AR=(Item*)malloc(STACK_SIZE*sizeof(Item));
}
```

параметр `STACK_AR` - это не глобальная переменная, как вы, по всей вилимости думаете, а это локальная переменная функции, которая содержит **копию** значения глобальной переменной с тем же именем `STACK_AR`, и которая будет удалена после выхода из функции. Поэтому изменение этой локальной переменной внутри функции никак не влияет на глобальную переменную.

Вам следовало бы определить эту функцию следющим образом

```
void stack_creation(Item **STACK_AR,int STACK_SIZE)
{
    *STACK_AR=(Item*)malloc(STACK_SIZE*sizeof(Item));
}
```

то есть передавать аргумент по ссылке.

И, соответственно, вызывать эту функцию следует как

```
stack_creation( &STACK_AR, STACK_SIZE );
```

EDIT: Я вижу, что вы подправили код и заменили `SIZE` га `STACK_SIZE`. Так что мое первое замечание можете игнорировать.

Comment: Спасибо большое Vlad, вы очень помогли.